# how to display properly single value from a StreamBuilder 'Cloud Firestore'

Tags: flutter, stream-builder, flutter-futurebuilder

i have data stored in filds like so [=> **image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLTwj.png)

i have followed the documentation, the data just refuses to show for some reason.

it looks somthing like this

```
StreamBuilder(
                  stream:
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {....}
     )
```

and  then

```
 if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                  print(snapshot.data.documents[0]['User Email']); 
....}
```

**note:** the stream works fine but im assuming this happening coz of the way im calling it the `snapshot.data.documents`

how can i properly call them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of the `[0]`.
When you read just one of the documents, refer to:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('yourDocument').snapshots();
```

and if you will read more then one you can use this:

```
 CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return new ListView(
      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
        return new ListTile(
          title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
          subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```